# React-Final-Form: It is taking initial value by default, how can I remove it?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

component="select" taking first option as initial selection, though it is not specified anywhere. How do i remove the initial selection for component="select" in react final form ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an empty option tag as the first option like this

```
 <Field name="favoriteColor" component="select">
    <option />
    <option value="#ff0000">❤️ Red</option>
    <option value="#00ff00"> Green</option>
    <option value="#0000ff"> Blue</option>
 </Field>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But adding this will create another blank option in my drop down and i can't add a placeholder.

Comment: Alright.... But what do you want to replace the initial selection with?

Comment: Yes, this is just a basic HTML question, unrelated to RFF or React.